# Getting Parsing error when consuming FileStreamResult Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an api that generates an excel file and returns a FileStreamResult as follows:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile( string id )
        {
         Stream stream = null;
         //code to generate file 

            return File( stream, "application/octet-stream", $"{id}.xlsx" ); // returns a FileStreamResult
        }
```

When I then try to call this api I do:

```
FileStreamResult response = (FileStreamResult)await _api.GetFile(id);
```

However I get the following error as well as a 200 Ok code:

Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: P. Path '', line 0, position 0.

However when I test the GetFile Api from postman it returns a response
I know this is a JSON error, but I am not sure how I can correctly handle the API response, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you cut some code in posting your example, but it looks to me like `stream` is null. If there is some missing code and you're hydrating the `stream`, you might consider setting `stream.Position = 0;` before sending it back. That said, I was able to make your model work with this code:

```
        [HttpGet("GetMyFile")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile(string id)
        {
            Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\temp\myfile.xlsx");
            //code to generate file 

            return File(stream, "application/octet-stream", $"{id}.xlsx"); // returns a FileStreamResult
        }
```

Comment: Sorry yes, I didnt include the code, but it calls another method and returns a stream result